# Finding the index of a character to match in a specific regex

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have a String that begins with a word and I want to make a substring which starts at index 0 and ends at the index of the next special character (`space`, `.`, `!`, `?`, etc...). How would I go about doing that with a regex? Can I get the index of the first regex match? And how would the pattern look?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following.

```
^\w+(?=\W)
```

**Explanation**:

```
^            # the beginning of the string
\w+          # word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times)
(?=          # look ahead to see if there is:
  \W         #   non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
)            # end of look-ahead
```

**Example**:

```
String s  = "foobar!";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\w+(?=\\W)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println("Start:" + m.start() + " End:" + m.end());
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How would I go about doing that with a regex?

You can try something like this:

```
^.*?\p{Punct}
```

- `^` matches start of string
- `.*?` matches anything [*reluctantly*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)
- `\p{Punct}` matches one of `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ ``

---

> Can I get the index of the first regex match?

In general, you can obtain the indices of regex matches with [`Matcher#start`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

The following prints the substring that contains the word part in your string (a `\w` denotes a word characters including digits, while `\W` denotes a non-word character):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)[\\W\\s]*");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("word!,(. [&]");
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output: `word`